# Retina image displayed too big in retina simulator

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios-simulator, cgcontext

I display a retina image (with @2x.png extension) using:

```
myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneBackground@2x.jpg"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);
[myImage drawAtPoint: CGPointZero];
myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
NSLog(@"Dimension:%f x %f",myImage.size.width,myImage.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

However the image is displayed twice its size on the retina simulation. Image and simulator both have 640 x 960 resolution, so I would expect the image filling the screen.
I know there are other ways than CGContext to display an image, but that's the way I would need to other purposes in my code.
Any idea why I have this definition issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use @2x suffix

From apple documentation:

> The UIImage class handles all of the work needed to load
>   high-resolution images into your app. When creating new image objects,
>   you use the same name to request both the standard and the
>   high-resolution versions of your image. For example, if you have two
>   image files, named Button.png and Button@2x.png, you would use the
>   following code to request your button image:
>
> `UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button"];`

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to explicitly load a retina image, @2x will be automatically appended to the image name if the device has a retina display.

Change your UIImage code to: `myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneBackground.jpg"];`